# bootstrap 3 modal dialog not rendering as it should

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-load

I have the following javascript code

```
$("#modal-yes-button").click(function (){
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    $(".modal-body").load('/url/that/returns/an/html/');
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

and the following modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>This is a question answer yes or later</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Maybe Later</button>
                <button id="modal-yes-button" class="btn btn-info" aria-hidden="true">Yes</button>

            </div>
        </div><!--modal-content-->
    </div><!--modal-dialog-->
</div><!--myModal-->
```

I want the usere to press the yes button hide the modal(it says that bootstrap won't allow modal open when another one is open) load the new html content for the .modal-body and dipslay the modal dialog again. Only what i get is black screen(like when it shadows for the modal to appear) but the modal never appears. I played with it using the chrome dev tools and the modal appears normally

chrome dev-tools

```
modaldialog = $("#myModal");
modaldlgBody = $(".modal-body");
modaldlgBody.load('/url/that/returns/html/');
modaldialog.modal('show');
```

With the above commands the new new "body" is loaded normally. But if i try to load the dialog first and then press the yes button even when triggering the modal from the chrome dev-tools i get the same behavour, black screen. What could be wrong?

chrome dev-tools that giving the same black screen

```
modaldialog = $("#myModal");
modaldialog.modal('show');
#pressing yes gets me the same black screen.
```

Comment: As a user suggested (who deleted his comment) i am showing the page after the ajax has loaded using this $(".modal-body").load('/url/that/returns/html/', function(){
                $("#myModal").modal('show');

            });
and works fine. But now it has the same behavour when i press the Maybe Later button. Dissmisses the modal, but I am not returned to my page but i just get the black shadowed page like the modal is there without content

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should wait for the closing animation to finish before reopening your dialog.

You can listen to the `hidden.bs.modal` event :

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Now, this would pop back your modal each time you close it, even when clicking on the "dismiss" button. You want to listen to this event only once, when the user clicks on the "Yes" button. You can take advantage of the `jQuery.one()` binder :

```
$('#modal-yes-button').click(function(){
   $('#myModal').one('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }); 
   $('#myModal').modal('hide');     
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jp9fC/1/)

---

But I don't see a good reason to keep the very same dialog open - it includes a "Yes" button with specific logic, which would need to be changed after the load completes ...

You can serve a complete dialog, using `$.get`, and simply display that :

```
$('#modal-yes-button').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    $.get(url, function(html){
        //html should contain a complete modal markup, including
        // .modal, .modal-header, .modal-body ...
        var $dlg = $(html);
        // if needed, add specific handlers :
        $dlg.on('click', '#whatever', function(){ /*do stuff*/ });
        $dlg.appendTo('body').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it better to load a whole new modal instead of editing the old?

Comment: I still get one backdrop left, should i use your listen for the hide event even if i use the get method to call a whole new dialog?

Comment: I still get two backdrop divs when i use either way, even if i use the one method.

Comment: Your code works for the same dialog, but it won't work if am loading another dialog, I get two backdrop divs, one from the new dlg and one from the previous one. Even if I use the one-method you suggested, and wrap the $.get() in the hidden.bs.modal event, still i get the same result. My script is inside html file before </body>

Answer (score 1):

The right answer should be placing the modal in the top of the document.

just before the body tag ends or just after the body tag start , there could be only one level of nesting

```
<body>  
<div>
    <!-- no other nesting -->
    <!-- put modal here -->
    <div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
       </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
         </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div><!-- .modal -->
     </div><!-- first div end here -->    
       </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked. I had to run the code

```
$dlg.appendTo('body');
$("#id_of_new_modal").modal('show');
```

instead of

```
$dlg.appendTo('body').modal('show');
```

I am not quite sure why this is like this. I thought using $ is a jquery object so

```
$dlg.appendTo('body').modal('show');
```

should have worked. But it didn't. If you have any ideas why please comment I like to know the why in things :)